# Evicting and Updating object using NHibernate nulls all references

Tags: nhibernate

I am investigating some unexpected behavior with NHibernate that needs more clarity.
I create a new object 'Request' and save it. I create another object 'AuditLog' and add request as a reference to AuditLog. I save that too.
Now, if the Request object is evicted from the session (for some reason), and updated again, the references in AuditLog is NULLified in the database when the transaction is committed.

Any ideas on why this would happen?

If the Request object is not created in the session, but retrieved from the database, and the same process runs, the reference in AuditLog is maintained.

Sample code which has been edited for ease in understanding.
If I remove the `session.Evict(request1)` from the code, the test passes. With this code, when the session closes, an additional query is fired on the DB to null the reference of request in AuditLog.

```
//Session 1
var session = Resolve<IFullSession>().Session();
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var request1 = new Request { Id = "REQ01" };
    request1.SetFieldValue("Type", "Stage1"); //Type is column in Request table
    session.Save("Request", request1);

    var auditLog1 = new AuditLog { Id = "LOG01" };
    auditLog1.SetFieldValue("Request", request1); //Request is reference column to AuditLog
    session.Save("AuditLog", auditLog1);

    session.Evict(request1);
    request1.SetFieldValue("Type", "Stage2");
    session.SaveOrUpdate("Request", request1);

    tx.Commit();
}
CreateInnerContainers(); // This closes earlier session.
//Session 2
var session2 = Resolve<IFullSession>().Session();
using (var tx = session2.BeginTransaction())
{
    var theLogObject = session2.Get<AuditLog>("LOG01");
    Assert.IsNotNull(theLogObject); // This is true
    Assert.IsNotNull(theLogObject.GetFieldValue("Request")); // This fails
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: When you say "evicted from session", what exactly do you refer to? Has the object been deleted? If so, then the reference would be removed due to cascading.

Comment: No the object is not deleted. It is just evicted from the session using Session.Evict(Request). As per my understanding, once I update the object and save it, it is added back to the session automatically.

Comment: Could you post the code where you evict the object up till transaction commit?

Comment: Added sample test code which depicts this behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can access session objects and use then whatever you like

```
session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntityEntries

but if I were you i would make sure that i'm evicting the right object and spend some time on debuging. Knowing what is going on is better than searching for workarounds

foreach (var e in session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntityEntries.Values.OfType<EntityType>().Where(<condition>))
{
    session.Evict(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Save call on the session doesn't mean that your entity is written to the underlying database. It will become persisted in the current persistence context (your session).

If you now remove this entity from the persistence context (what you do with "evict"), your session will not be able to save it on flush (transaction end).

Try to call session.Flush() just before session.Evict(request1) and see what happens.

I do not know NHibernate, I'm coming from hibernate, but eventually this helps to clarify.

Comment: I did try Flush() before the evict, but the problem still persists